# AzureのCustom Visionで学習させるデータに一つの画像をアフィン変換したものを入れても効果があるのか

Tags: azure

現在AzureのCustom Visionを使いはじめたものです。

30枚程度の画像を学習させたところまだ精度が高くなかったので、精度をあげるために1000枚くらいの画像を学習させようと思っています。

その際に、もともとある画像をアフィン変換をして複数枚の画像に水増しをしようと思いました。
しかし、もしかしたらCustom Visionのアルゴリズムの中で既にそのような幾何学的な画像データの水増しは行われているのでは、と思い質問させていただきました。

わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

内部で使用されているアルゴリズムは不明ですが、アフィン変換したものは見かけ上の精度があがるかもしれませんが実際に有効なものになるかは何とも言えません。もともと少量のデータでも効率がいいらしいので内部的に行っている可能性もありますが…

まずはこちらのガイドラインに従ってみてはどうでしょうか。（ラベル毎に50個～が出発点のようです）

- [分類子を改善する方法](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/getting-started-improving-your-classifier)

Answer (score 0):

kosmos.ebi様
ご回答大変ありがとうございました。アカウントでトラブルが起きてしまったため別アカウントからお礼申し上げます。

> アフィン変換したものは見かけ上の精度があがるかもしれませんが実際に有効なものになるかは何とも言えません。

実際に30枚の学習画像を300枚に水増しし（幾何学的変換に加え、コントラストと彩度をランダムに調整しました）、追加で学習させたところ、精度が目に見えて上がり、もともと大きい数値（99.99%など）しか返ってこなかったのが、80%以下の数値も返ってくるようになり、「そのモノらしさ」を数値でうまく表されているような気がします。

> もともと少量のデータでも効率がいいらしいので内部的に行っている可能性もありますが…

おっしゃる通りですね。10枚程度の学習でもそれなりの精度が得られていることから内部でData Augmentationもしくはそれに準ずる処理が行われているという推論が十分に可能ですよね。

とりあえず、今回は結果だけみれば機能が向上したのでこのまま進めようと思います。
ご回答大変ありがとうございました。